# Second-Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$xy'' + 2y' = 12x^2$$

Solve this by substituting $u = y'$

When I do this I get $u = y' = \frac{4x^3 + C}{2x}$

How do I continue?

Thanks

Comment: separating variables  equation $y' =\frac{4x^3 + C}{2x}\Rightarrow dy=\frac{4x^3 + C}{2x}dx$

Comment: And what am I supposed to do with that information?

Comment: I'm not sure your solution for $u$ is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $u=y'$ gives an an equation for $u$:
$$
x u' + 2u = 12 x^2 \implies u' + \frac{2}{x} u = 12x
$$
This differential equation is linear with integrating factor 
$$
p = e^{\int \frac{2}{x}\,dx} = e^{2 \ln x} = x^2
$$
Multiplying through we have
\begin{align*}
x^2 u' + 2x u &= 12x^3 \\
\implies (x^2u)' &= 12x^3 \\
\implies x^2 u &= 3x^4+ C \\
\implies u &= 3x^2 + \frac{C}{x^2}
\end{align*}
You can check that $u$ satisfies the desired equation, for
\begin{align*}
    u' &= 6x - \frac{2C}{x^3} \\
   xu' &= 6x^2 - \frac{2C}{x^2} \\
   2u  &= 6x^2 + \frac{2C}{x^2} \\
\end{align*}
The sum of the RHS of the last two equations is $12x^2$.

But you wanted $y$, not $u$.  No problem; we know
$$
   y' = 3x^2 + Cx^{-2} \implies y = x^3 - C x^{-1} + D = x^3 - \frac{C}{x} + D
$$
You can check this $y$ function satisfies your original DE.